# Why does groupmod <tab><tab> show me my folders and not my groups?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I was trying to solve Virtualbox's USB problem by adding my username to the vboxusers group, but when I tried to see if the group existed by using groupmod **TAB** **TAB** all I got was what appears to be my home directory.

Why is that? What can I do to see the groups on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bash and the default bash-completion rules do not autocomplete groups for these commands, you can use something like the following (either by running once on the terminal or permenently by including it in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.

```
complete -g groupmod groupdel newgrp
```

Another way to see all of the groups is to look in the /etc/group file. Also, the "groups" command will allow you to see which groups you are a member of (and which groups other users are members of).